# Cisco IOS XR policy statistics:

Tags: qos, cisco-ios-xr

My goal is to see if the interface gets more than 2gbps of traffic, just to see if it's true.

So I created a policy map with ACL that matches all, and all actions - violate, conform are set to transmit.

It looks like this:

```
ipv4 access-list test_for_isp
 10 permit ipv4 any any
class-map match-any class_test_isp
 match access-group ipv4 test_for_isp
 end-class-map
! 
policy-map traffic_test
 class class_test_isp
  police rate 1900 mbps 
   conform-action transmit
   exceed-action transmit
   violate-action transmit
  ! 
 ! 
 class class-default
 ! 
 end-policy-map
```

but i dont see any counters:

```
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ASR02#show policy-map interface all
Mon Sep 18 13:38:16.435 Summer
node0_0_CPU0: 
TenGigE0/0/2/3 input: traffic_test
Class class_test_simcentric
  Classification statistics          (packets/bytes)     (rate - kbps)
    Matched             :                   0/0                    0
    Transmitted         : N/A 
    Total Dropped       :                   0/0                    0
  Policing statistics                (packets/bytes)     (rate - kbps) 
    Policed(conform)    :                   0/0                    0
    Policed(exceed)     :                   0/0                    0
    Policed(violate)    :                   0/0                    0
    Policed and dropped :                   0/0                  
Class class-default
  Classification statistics          (packets/bytes)     (rate - kbps)
    Matched             :                   0/0                    0
    Transmitted         : N/A 
    Total Dropped       : N/A
```

So, please advise,

1. Is my configuration bad?
2. Are there any additional statistics that should be enabled?
3. Maybe there're any other ways to see burst/peak rates on interfaces - using IOS XR.

Comment: Are you applying the policy on the input or output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following commands:

```
show qos interface TenGigE 0/0/2/3 input

show qos interface TenGigE 0/0/2/3 output
```

You can check further at [Cisco Page](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/xr12000/software/xr12k_r4-2/qos/command/reference/b_qos_cr42xr12k/b_qos_cr42xr12k_chapter_01.html#wp4161357990)

Comment: than you, seems my previuos command works. It was a problem that the only traffic i received in previous setup was a control plane traffic (BGP, ARP).

Comment: Good to know that :)!